# I know what I need to do but dont know how to apply: the question related to The first order approximation theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, approximation

$\mathbf{Question:}$

Prove that

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin(2x+2y)-2x-2y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=0$

$\mathbf{My\ ideas:}$

I will use the First Order Approximation Theorem.

But how can I apply this?

Please show me understanbly clear because this is my first example related to the theorem. I want to learn.  Thank you:)

Comment: Try to re-write it into polar coordinates, maybe it helps.

Comment: According to this theorem, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-[f(x)+Df(x).h]}{||h||}=0$. Can you translate this limit accourding to my question? @igf I could not do:(

Comment: @B11b: What book are you using that is using this confusing terminology. Are you merely trying to figure out how to do the multivariable limit? The terminology you are using is quite confusing and makes it hard for people to help. Perhaps you can add the details of this to your question. What is the First Order Approximation Theorem? Regards

Comment: Fitzpatrick's advanced calculus book. Similarly, I am confused too much as well. Thanks.. @Amzoti

Comment: I saw a way is:$y=ax$,then it is $\dfrac{sin(2(1+a)x)-2(1+a)x}{x\sqrt{1+a^2}}$,then you can get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  the gradient $\nabla f(0,0)$ of $f(x,y)=\sin(2x+2y)$ at $(0,0)$ is the vector

$$\nabla f(0,0)=(2,2), $$

as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2\cos(2x+2y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2\cos(2x-2y).$

$f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ (which implies $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$) if

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\langle \nabla f(0,0),(x,y)\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, $$

i.e.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\langle(2,2),(x,y)\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, $$

or

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\sin(2x+2y)-2x-2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, $$

which is the limit you consider. I used the fact that

$$f(0,0)=0,$$
$$\langle \nabla f(0,0),(x,y)\rangle=2x+2y,$$
$$\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}. $$

To compute such limit, consider it along the $x$-axis, for all points $(x,0)$ going to $(0,0)$, or the $y$-axis (all points $(0,x)$ going to $(0,0)$). Can you compute it in these 2 special cases?

Comment: In my answer I show a little problem concerning the limit you propose: are you sure that the function in the limit is $\sin(2x-2y)-2x-2y$ and not $\sin(2x-2y)-2x+2y$?

Comment: With $\sin(2x - 2y) - 2x - 2y$ the limit would not be $0$.  Try e.g. $x = 0$.

Comment: Aow sorry, I wrote Wrong I editted immediately! $\sin(2x+2y)-2x-2y$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I put the limit =0 in my answerbut actually I did not compute it! I remove it, now. ps: you are right.

Comment: So sorry:( @Avitus

Comment: Plus sign is in "sin" not between $2x$ and $2y$ @avitus

Comment: @B11b ok, now the signs make sense! I edit my answer as a hint (check the limit along the x or y axis...)

Comment: By the way, I could not understand how do you go from the first limit equation to the last limit equation ? @Avitus

Comment: Please can you explain there a little bit? @Avitus

Comment: @B11b I added some more details, hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes! Of course! $lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac {sin(2x)-2x}{|x|}=0 $ similarly, I compute y-axis for $(0,y) \to (0,0)$ I will obtain the limit as zero. So the limit is proved to equal to zero. Right? @Avitus